# In Haskell, what does `Con Int` mean?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, declaration, type-constructor

In the 1995 paper by Philip Wadler ["Monads for functional programming"](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf) he gives an example of an evaluator:

> ```
> data Term = Con Int | Div Term Term
> ```

What does `Con Int` mean in this context?

It seems like the expression `data Term = Int | Div Term Term` is doing exactly the same thing. I tried googling various subsets of the words "Hakell", "type", "constructor", "constant" and "integer" but could't find anything useful.

Why do we need `Con`?

Comment: It's literally explained on the next line: _"A term is either a constant Con a, where a is an integer, or a quotient, Div t u, where t and u are terms."_ `Con Int` -> constant integer.

Comment: `3` has type `Int`. `Con 3` has type `Term`. The `Con` constructor is needed to separate these two distinct (yet related) values. Also, `data Term = Int | ...` defines a new constant named `Int` which is completely unrelated to the type `Int`. It could be called anything else with similar effect e.g. `data Term = Foo | ...`. This is not equivalent to the original type which allowed integers as terms.

Comment: Though the suggested question asks about why `Maybe` needs its `Just` constructor, the underlying issue is the same.

Comment: `Int` would be a new nullary data constructor of type `Term`, not a unary constructor of type `Int -> Term` that wraps an arbitrary integer value.

Comment: It was a perfectly reasonable question.  Next time you have a Haskell question, consider tagging it with only `haskell` without any general tags.  Those who follow the `haskell` tag usually do a good job of answering beginner questions; other tags may attract different "answer cultures".